# Redo a Reverted git merge

Tags: git

I have a branch called **dev** and a topic branch off of it called **feature-1**. After testing, I want to merge feature-1 into dev. But first, changes were made to dev while I was working on feature-1, so I thought to merge them:

```
git checkout feature-1
git merge dev
```

Worked fine, but then without realizing it, I accidentally deleted the new files, and un-did the deletion of files that happened in dev. I figured, "whatever, I'll commit and merge again later."

```
git add new-files
git rm old-files
git commit -m "broke merge"
```

But then I was unable to re-merge:

```
git merge dev
>>>>> Already up to date
```

But...there are differences in the files between these branches! If I merge feature-1 into dev, won't it play those deletion commits on top of dev?

I tried reverting the merge:

```
git revert -m 1 *merge-hash*
```

But git still thinks one is the parent of the other, or something. Merging again still fails "already up to date".

After this I also tried rebasing dev onto feature-1, but I still don't see the changes from dev, and by this point, I'm lost.

I don't care that dev is still considered a parent of feature-1, or whatever. I just want to replay dev's commits on top of feature-1 and resolve any conflicts. How can I do this?

EDIT: I tried reverting my revert on a suggestion from Linus I read [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt)

```
git revert *revert-hash*
```

Now I see all the changes from dev (I THINK). It's not obvious from the git log which commits happened in what order now.

EDIT 2: Then I ran git status and found

> On branch feature-1
> Your branch and 'origin/feature-1' have diverged,
> and have 5 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
> (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

So I ran git pull, resolved merge conflicts....and I've lost the changes from dev again, of course because I pushed that bad merge earlier. Maybe this was due to the rebase?

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: Since you don't like what you did to feature1, starting with the reverse merge, why not just reset hard back to before you did those bad things?

Comment: After having deleted the files merged in from the dev branch, how can I "replay the dev commits" to get them back?

Comment: You keep saying "replay". I don't think that word means what you think it does.

Comment: I don't think I understand it either. I'm still learning git. How do I fix this with reset hard?

Comment: The problem started when you said `git checkout feature-1` and `git merge dev`. You were on some commit when you said that. So `git reset --hard thatCommit` and everything will be just as it was before you said it. It was all just a dream. :)

Comment: I see. Indeed that works too! Regarding my understanding, is it not the case that *merging* one branch into another is akin to taking this stack of changes, lay them on top of my current stack, and pop them or "replay?"

Comment: Yes, it is not the case. Not quite, anyway. You might enjoy this blog post of mine: https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happens to me, many times the easiest solution is to create a new branch from dev, and `git cherry-pick` your changes from feature-1, one commit at the time. That way you end up with exactly the commits you want, instead of trying to fix a broken history that will look ugly anyway.

Another solution is to rebase **against** the branch you want, and clean it up of commits

In feature-1 branch run `rebase dev -i`. Then remove the commits you don't want by replacing `pick` with `d`.

The rebase option is better when you know what the issue with the history is. The cherry-pick one is better when you don't know what's going on, and is generally more time consuming but easier.

A middle-of-the-road solution is to rebase, merge commits you know are good, and then cherry-pick them onto another, clean branch. I rarely ever do this.

If you solve the issue locally using `rebase -i`, git wont let you push since you've modified the history. You can solve it by force push so origin matches your local: `git push --force-with-lease`. Push force is required whenever you rebase -i since you're changing the history.

Comment: This interactive rebasing is super neat! Maybe it would've solved my problem had I not also pushed this bad merge to the remote. As it stands, `feature-1` and `origin/feature-1` have diverged, and this doesn't help with that.

Comment: If you solve the issue locally you can force push so origin matches your local: `git push --force-with-lease`. That will force remote to accept your changes.

Push force is required whenever you `rebase -i` since you're changing the history.